# ubuntu 21.04 attach keyboard shortcuts to scripts

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.04

I knew how to create bash scripts and attach them to keyboard shortcuts in previous ubuntu versions, but it doesn't seem to work in ubuntu 21.04.
so I wanted to know how to do that?
(I try to create an "open terminal here" shortcut).

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A site and only one question should be asked a time. Please choose which of your questions you wish to have answered in this one and post the other a separate question to prevent the whole thing being closed as needing more focus. You can reference [ask] to get the run down.

Comment: Clarify your question and make it specific.

Comment: vanadium, 24601:
thanks for bringing this to my attention, I've edited the post accordingly.